# how extract features from mfcc coefficients

Tags: speech-recognition, feature-extraction, mfcc

I have successfully extracted MFCC coefficients and i have got below values

```
  -15.2366
    6.4996
   -2.1807
    0.2495
   -1.3403
    0.9815
   -0.1106
    1.7914
    0.7311
    1.1881
    1.3340
    2.6080
    1.4208
    2.0144
    0.5085
   -1.1236
   -1.2728
   -0.9470
   -0.8139
    0.8987
    1.6006
    1.6000
    0.4638
    0.3747
    0.0670
   -0.0620
    0.6234
    0.0614
    0.0964
    0.2334
   -0.2188
    0.0591
    0.6765
    0.3943
   -0.1409
    0.1894
    0.0004
   -0.4762
   -0.1273
    0.1655
   -0.0649
   -0.2606
    0.0075
   -0.1275
   -0.2038
   -0.1332
    0.2084
    0.5128
    0.8877
    0.5406
```

now how to extract features from these values.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

MFCCs are already the features you have to use to train your recognition engine (usually HMM).

However, how did you extracted those features?
I would assume that vector represents the MFCC of a single 100ms window in the audio file you are dealing with, since typical MFCCs look like a N-by-M matrix.
N is the number of windows you used to extract the features, and M depends on how you extracted the MFCCs (M=39, usually).